# iOS Alignment Works properly in iPhone 5 but not in iPhone 6 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode6

Issue is icons displaying properly in iPhone 5 but when comes to iPhone 6 all icons moved little left side.[This image is taken from iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgfHa.jpg)

Comment: iPhone 6's screen is wider... so your icons are probably aligned to the left?

Comment: any solution for fit the screen in every iphones?

Comment: you need to make some autolayouts that will align them relative to each other and the center, rather than the edges of the screen, cant really help you beyond that im afraid